# How to match SQL results from two lists and insert a new row for each match found?

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.9

For those familiar with Magento, I'm attempting to write a query to create new upsell entries in the `catalog_product_link` table, but with some unique criteria. My knowledge of MySQL (or any SQL) is basic at best.

I have two types of products in a table, which I can uniquely identify by joining a few other tables. I can get a unique list of the two types of product results like so:

```
SELECT cpev.entity_id AS product_id, cpev.value AS name
FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar AS cpev

INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity AS cpe
ON cpe.entity_id = cpev.entity_id

INNER JOIN eav_attribute AS ea
ON ea.attribute_id = cpev.attribute_id

INNER JOIN catalog_category_product AS cat
ON cat.product_id = cpev.entity_id

WHERE cat.category_id IN ( 41 )
AND ea.attribute_code = 'name'

GROUP BY product_id
ORDER BY product_id;
```

...where the two lists of results are based on changing `WHERE cat.category_id IN ( 41 )`.

What I'm attempting to do is match a single row from the first list of results to one or more rows from the second list based on the name. The full name from the first list will match the first portion of the name from the second list plus some text; for example:

- list1, name: Afinia L801
- list2, name: Afinia L801 On-site Maintenance
  Contract

For each match, I need to insert a new row in a different table, like so:

```
INSERT INTO catalog_product_link (product_id, linked_product_id, link_type_id)
SELECT @idFromList1 AS product_id, @idFromList2 as linked_product_id, 4 as link_type_id
...
```

I'm not sure if this is something that can be accomplished with only SQL, or if this is a case where I need to write (for example) a PHP script to pull the two lists from the db, match them up, and then insert the results. But I'm still learning SQL so I'm trying to get a better grasp of what I can do with just a MySQL query.

Comment: Which column has the name? What is the other category number you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can select from the same table twice.

```
SELECT cpev.entity_id AS product_id, cpev.value AS name
FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar AS cpev
INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity AS cpe
ON cpe.entity_id = cpev.entity_id
INNER JOIN eav_attribute AS ea
ON ea.attribute_id = cpev.attribute_id
INNER JOIN catalog_category_product AS cat
ON cat.product_id = cpev.entity_id
INNER JOIN catalog_category_product AS cat2
ON cat2.product_id = cpev.entity_id
WHERE cat.category_id IN ( 41 )
AND cat2.category_id IN ( 42 )
AND ea.attribute_code = 'name'
GROUP BY product_id
ORDER BY product_id;
```